# Need help deciphering markings on an electrolytic capacitor

Tags: capacitor, markings

I have a capacitor which is marked with "1200uF200wv". What does the "w" mean?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `W` is for `Working`; `WV` = Working Voltage

Comment: Why should something be simple when it can be complicated :)

Comment: @AndrejaKo: and to think that the answer could have been shorter, but E&R insists on a minimum of 30 characters :-)